# Blender scene freezes between different steps of execution

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to use a python script in blender which places certain animations at each step. Initially, I couldnt see anything on the screen until the last step, as blender was freezing during whole operation, but, I was told to use modal operators to avoid this problem. I used them and now I can see different step animations in between. The change of steps is triggered using keystroke.

However, still in between changing steps, I cannot zoom or edit on the blender scene. The intend is, once I have imported images or animation on blender scene, I want to even modify the shape and size after each step manually. But, the screen is freezes until I dont send next keystroke to change the resources on the scene.

The modal operator I have implemented is as below:

```
class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):

        print("MODAL")
        if event.type == 'TIMER':           
            print("Inside modal handler timer")
            keystroke = receivedFromServer()
            executeInstructions(keystroke)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}



    def execute(self, context):
        print("EXECUTE")
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self) # add modal handler!!!
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("INVOKE")

        return self.execute(context)
```

Is there anyway to avoid the freezing of blender scene in between changing step, such that I can edit the objects on the scene manually before sending new keystroke from the server?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The idea is that user will enter an input command on server, which should be directed to the client ( which is at blender side to display objects on scene ). I tried what you suggested but got an error under 'execute method' saying 'RUNNING_MODAL' is not compatible. "RuntimeError: class OBJECT_OT_modal_operator, function invoke: incompatible return value , str(, Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType)"

Comment: @batFINGER made changes as you suggested, however, now the moment blender reaches modal operator code, it results in coredump. ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: RuntimeError: class OBJECT_OT_modal_operator, function invoke: incompatible return value , str(, Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType)
Writing: /tmp/BlenderClient.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for editing and suggesting changes. I didnt write 'return' in the invoke method. I am pretty new to modal operators and have no clue about how they work, or what are the possible return values for each method involved. However, still the screen freezes between resources display on the scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31164/discussion-between-blackbug-and-batfinger).